# GCM push notification message outside data dictionary

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to retrieve the key "message" on the device when sending notification to GCM.

```
   { "collapse_key" : "score",
     "data" : { "k1" : "v1" },
     "message" : "Hello World!",
     "registration_ids" : [ "DEVICE_REGISTRATION_ID_GOES_HERE" ]
   }
```

From the intent.getExtras(), I'm able to receive the following keys "**collapse_key**", "**from**", "**k1**" and their corresponding values as well. However I do not get key "**message**". If I do not add anything in the "**data**" dictionary, I still get push notification without "**k1**" (as expected).

Push to GCM does not result in errors. Does GCM drop keys not mentioned in "**data**" dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the way you have it won't work. Anything you want to add, make it part of the data object:

```
{
    "collapse_key": "score",
    "data": {
        "k1": "v1",
        "message": "Hello World!"
    },
    "registration_ids": [
        "DEVICE_REGISTRATION_ID_GOES_HERE"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm fully aware of what you said. My question specifically is what does GCM do to the key value that is not part of data dictionary. If I send extra key value outside data, it happily accepts and doesn't pass it to device. Or maybe it does in a different way. I don't know. It is not documented anywhere. Do you have any pointers here?